# How to get the text value from my select populated with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I populated a select dropdown menu with mysql data using php

```
<select name="course" onchange="tester()"> 
    <option>Select Course</option>
      <?php $result= mysql_query('SELECT DISTINCT Course FROM tasks'); ?> 
      <?php while($row= mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { ?> 
        <option value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['Course']);?>"> 
            <?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['Course']); ?> 
        </option> 
      <?php } 
      ?> 
</select>
```

to be printed on change by the `tester()` function

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
  function tester()
  {
    var testMe = $('#course option:selected').text()
    alert(testMe);
  }
</script>
```

to which I receive the alert:

```
"The page at localhost says: undefined"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$('#course option:selected')` isn't defined.

In your html you have:

```
<select name="course" onchange="tester()">
```

If you want to use the `#course` selector, you need to add an **id** to the HTML code.

ie.

```
<select id="course" name="course" onchange="tester()">
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your script runs *after* `#course option:selected` is defined.

It's good practice to wrap your code in a `.ready` call. This ensures all the (static) HTML has loaded.